# Draw image pixel array on MFC dialog

Tags: c++, image, mfc, dialog, gdi+

I have a 'pbm' image whose content is loaded into a IMAGE object which is defined as below.

My problem current is how to plot this picture on a MFC dialog (I current want to draw it on the MFC dialog). My code below does not generate any result.

```
struct header {
    int nr, nc;             /* Rows and columns in the image */
    int oi, oj;             /* Origin */
};

/*      The IMAGE data structure        */
struct image {
        struct header *info;            /* Pointer to header */
        unsigned char **data;           /* Pixel values */
};

void CSampleDlg::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
    char* lpszPathName = "TESTPAGE.PBM";
    IMAGE image = Input_PBM(lpszPathName);
    for(int i=0; i< image->info->nc; i++){
        for(int j=0; j< image->info->nr; j++){
            unsigned char pixel = image->data[j][i];
           //pixel value is either 0  or 1..
            dc.SetPixel(i,j,pixel);   //PLOT The whole image....
        }   
    }

    Invalidate(0);
}

HRESULT CSampleDlg::OnButtonOK(IHTMLElement* /*pElement*/)
{
    OnPaint();
    return S_OK;
}
```

In the `OnPaint()`, i called dc->setPixel(..) to redraw the whole image by drawing each pixel. But the dialog does not change...

Comment: Aside from the inefficiency of loading a bitmap every time you paint, you need to 1. create a compatible memory dc, 2. create a compatible bitmap, 3. select the bitmap into the dc, 4. draw on the bitmap, 5. blit the bitmap to the paint dc. There are a huge number of internet resources showing how to do this.

Comment: It is never correct to call OnPaint. Remove that call and replace it with Invalidate(). That will cause Windows to call OnPaint correctly.  Then in your OnPaint remove the call to Invalidate(): It will cause an infinite loop.